# Python with MongoDB - count() function only works with empty search?

Tags: python, mongodb

i have a strange problem with my python script.
I need to get a totalnumber of database entrys in my MongoDB

```
>>> a = _chatlog.find()
>>> a.count()
4120
```

Works just like i planned, yay

Now things get strange:

```
>>> b = _chatlog.find({ "$query": {}, "$orderby": { "_id" : -1 }})
>>> b.count()
0
```

I perform this Query because i need all entrys in descending order.
First i expected a empty cursor but its not:

```
for data in b:
c += 1

>>> c
4120
```

How do i get the count method to work properly when i perform querys?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `orderby` clause and tried?

Comment: tried it, same problem

Comment: Try the same in the console. Does it work?

Answer (score 2):

Count and sort are not compatible. (Nor is it meaningful to combine a sort order with a count.) Remove the `$orderby` from your query.

Note that if you use the `sort` method instead of including `$orderby`, `count` will work as expected:

`collection.find().sort([('_id', -1)]).count()`

This works because `count` simply *ignores* the sort order. I reiterate that it's meaningless to combine sorting and counting.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why query modifiers aren't working but they aren't working for me either. Are you using an older version of Mongo?

Is it possible for you to use ".sort()" instead?

From:

```
b = _chatlog.find({ "$query": {}, "$orderby": { "_id" : -1 }}).count()
```

To:

```
b = _chatlog.find({}).sort({_id:-1}).count()
```

Comment: Hi, unfortuneately you solution throws an exception: TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list edit: im using the latest stable verison of mongodb

Comment: The proper syntax there is, `sort([('_id', 1)])`. PyMongo won't accept a dictionary argument to `sort` because dictionaries don't preserve key order, and key order is important for sorting.